# t-sql select all values based on top 5 query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been hunting through documentation and examples and playing to try and make this work but am having no luck so I'm hoping someone might point me in the right direction.

I have my top 5 items from a table called maintenance via query based the month, basically giving me the top 5 nodes with the highest calls this month.

Ex. Top 5 select

```
select top 5  
  maint.node_id
  ,maint.sc_tot
FROM
  server.dbo.maintenance as maint
where
    maint.province_name='provname
and
    maint.system_code='syscode'
and
    maint.city_name='cityname'
and
( 
    year(maint.startdate)=2015
    and 
    month(maint.startdate)=07
)
group by
  maint.node_id
  ,maint.sc_tot

order by
sum(isnull(maint.je_tot,0)+isnull(maint.sc_tot,0)+isnull(maint.tt_tot,0))
desc
```

Output is

```
node_id sc_tot
node1   30
node2   28
node3   27
node4   23
node5   23
```

What I need to do is to now select the sum of the calls for the month for each of those nodes without a time frame. Basically giving me the history and ultimately the trend for each node, from the same maintenance table.

Ex. Quick summary(not exact details)

```
node startdate sc_tot
node1 jan       10
node1 feb       15
node1 mar       36
node2 jan       14
node2 feb       22
etc....
```

This query will then be used in sql report builder for some reporting and graphing, but as long as i have the values I'm good.

Is this possible with just a single sql query?

Comment: Can you just put that query as a cte? Then create your larger query and join to your cte on node_id

Comment: CTE = common table expression.  Syntax is `with t1 as (Select...), t2 As (Select...) SELECT * from T1 INNER JOIN t2 on T1.ID = T2.FK`  essentially it's like a view created at run time that allows you to select from it and join to it like you would a view or table.  Makes reading queries easier and separates out concepts.  Could be accomplished using inline views as well; but generally those are not as easy to read/maintain.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cte.
Can you give me an example of what you are referencing with a larger query and joining on that?

Comment: Ohh, beaten by 18 seconds on the reply about the cte ;)
Yeah I've tried that but to not luck.
Would anyone be able to help me on the proper approach to that?

Comment: Can you post your CTE attempt, and what was wrong with the results?

Comment: The example that @xQbert posted is pretty much the way to do this. We can't give you any details because we don't know your tables.

Comment: It's just the one table, maintenance from the example where i get the top 5.

Comment: No real need for a CTE in this case, it's just one table and the aggregation can be done on any part of a date field, by adding that in the group by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNTESTED...

Perhaps something like...

I think you're after the top 5 nodes with the highest call volume in July of 2015, and then you want the node history by month/year of everything in the system for those top 5 nodes.

```
WITH CTE AS (   
  SELECT top 5 a.node_id, a.sc_tot
  FROM server.dbo.maintenance as a
  WHERE a.province_name='provname'
    and a.system_code='syscode'
    and a.city_name='cityname'
    and year(a.startdate)=2015
    and month(a.startdate)=07
  GROUP BY a.node_id ,a.sc_tot
  order by sum(isnull(a.je_tot,0)+isnull(a.sc_tot,0)+isnull(a.tt_tot,0)) desc)


SELECT TopRec.node_ID, sum(maint.sc_tot) as SumOfCalls, 
       year(maint.startdate) as YR, month(maint.startdate) as MO
FROM CTE as TopRec
INNER JOIN server.dbo.maintenance as maint
  on CTE.Node_Id = Maint.Node_ID
GROUP BY TopRec.node_ID, year(maint.startdate), month(maint.startdate)
```

This is essentially the same as this (inline view): but using a newer technique...  you can see why people prefer it for readability.

```
SELECT TopRec.node_ID, sum(maint.sc_tot) as SumOfCalls, 
       year(maint.startdate) as YR, month(maint.startdate) as MO
FROM (    
  SELECT top 5 a.node_id, a.sc_tot
  FROM server.dbo.maintenance as a
  WHERE a.province_name='provname'
    and a.system_code='syscode'
    and a.city_name='cityname'
    and year(a.startdate)=2015
    and month(a.startdate)=07
  GROUP BY a.node_id ,a.sc_tot
  order by sum(isnull(a.je_tot,0)+isnull(a.sc_tot,0)+isnull(a.tt_tot,0)) desc)) 
  as TopRec
  INNER JOIN server.dbo.maintenance as maint
    on CTE.Node_Id = Maint.Node_ID
  GROUP BY TopRec.node_ID, year(maint.startdate), month(maint.startdate)
```

Comment: Thanks :D
I see where you are going with that now. I was just starting to read about CTE as I've never used it before but seeing an example in direct relation to what I'm working on is an immense help!
I'll do some testing and see how it works.

Comment: A little tweaking and it works perfectly! Verified data by pulling nodes individually, manually and it's bang on.
Thanks so much for the help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
select top 5  
  maint.node_id
  ,convert(char(3), maint.startdate, 0) [mon]
  ,maint.sc_tot
FROM
  server.dbo.maintenance as maint
where
    maint.province_name='provname'
and
    maint.system_code='syscode'
and
    maint.city_name='cityname'
and
    year(maint.startdate)=2015
group by
  maint.node_id
  ,month(maint.startdate)
  ,maint.sc_tot

order by
sum(isnull(maint.je_tot,0)+isnull(maint.sc_tot,0)+isnull(maint.tt_tot,0))
desc
```

Though *UNTESTED*

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I thought the OP was after the all historical information for only the 5 nodes having the most calls in July of 2015.  Wouldn't this return the top 5 nodes by month in for 2015? which could be different than the top 5 nodes having calls in july?

Comment: I couldn't get this method to function, but the previous example did the trick. Thanks for posting your suggestion though :)

Comment: @xQbert perhaps I misunderstood it by looking at the sample dataset.